# Could Not Resolve Zxing Dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, barcode, zxing

In a week, I struggled with some errors on Android Studio.

**I want add Zxing Library dependencies in my project. But everytime I add the dependencies. I got this error**

```
"Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve..."
```

I did remove "compile" with "implementation" on every dependencies that I'm looking for.

**FYI: I've succeeded add Volley Library. No error appear.**

This is my TOP build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my APP build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "id.plevia.projectx.app"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"


    }

    buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':feature')
    implementation project(':base')
    implementation('com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1')
}
```

This is my BASE build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    baseFeature true
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    application project(':app')
    feature project(':feature')
    implementation('com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1')
}
```

This is my FEATURE build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':base')
    implementation('com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```

**All the build.gradle script above without Zxing dependency.**

All I want to do is to **make Barcode Scanner without pressing a button on every scan**

Thank you.

Comment: **Uncheck Offline work option**
_File->Other Settings->Default Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle->Uncheck Offline work option_

Comment: Wow. @Arbaz.in you make me amaze. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Arbaz.in answer in comment section. The answer of my problems is
**Uncheck Offline work option**

*File->Other Settings->Default Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle->Uncheck Offline work option*

Comment: Happy coding :D